# setting up a kubernetes cluster using aws and vagrant

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, vagrant, devops

I am studying kubernetes. I want to build a cluster consisting of 2 worker nodes and 1 master node in AWS using vagrant. i was able to launch an EC2 instance using the vagrant-aws plugin, but i don't know how to set up a cluster, can you please help me out if it's possible?
thank you

Comment: Have you already checked [this](https://blog.exxactcorp.com/building-a-kubernetes-cluster-using-vagrant/)?

Answer (score 0):

You can create cluster using `kubeadm` tool.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/